# Group by query performance with composite keys

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

recently I joined new company and their database design contains only of composite keys and they are only created for queries.

Tables look like this (some of the column names are anomyzed): (`instance_id` in tables stands as an ID for a client)

`app Table:`

```
CREATE TABLE `app`
(
    `instance_id`       varchar(36) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
    `app_id`            varchar(36) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
    `is_live`           tinyint(1)                                      NOT NULL,
    `created`           datetime(3)                                     NOT NULL,
    `modified`          datetime                                        NOT NULL,
    `start`             datetime                                        NOT NULL      DEFAULT '9000-12-31 23:59:59',
    `end`               datetime                                        NOT NULL      DEFAULT '9000-12-31 23:59:59',
    `status`            varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT '[INACTIVE|ACTIVE|...]',
    `title`             varchar(130) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin        DEFAULT NULL,
    `user_id`           varchar(36) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin               DEFAULT NULL,
    `type`              varchar(36) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin              DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`instance_id`, `is_live`, `app_id`),
    KEY `instance_id` (`instance_id`, `created`, `status`),
    KEY `is_live_created_idx` (`is_live`, `created`),
    KEY `app_start_idx` (`is_live`, `start`),
    KEY `created_index` (`created`),
    KEY `modified_index` (`modified`),
    KEY `app_end_index` (`instance_id`, `end`),
    KEY `app_by_id_idx` (`app_id`, `is_live`, `status`),
    KEY `instance_title_index` (`instance_id`, `is_live`, `title`),
    KEY `user_index` (`instance_id`, `is_live`, `app_id`, `user_id`),
    KEY `type_index` (`instance_id`, `type`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

`app_category Table:`

```
CREATE TABLE `app_categories_apps` (
  `instance_id`         varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `category_id`         varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `app_id`              varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`instance_id`, `category_id`, `app_id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
  COLLATE = utf8mb4_bin
  ROW_FORMAT = COMPRESSED;
```

And have query:

```
SELECT ca.category_id, e.status, count(ca.app_id)
    FROM app_categories_apps AS ca
    JOIN app AS e ON (e.instance_id = ca.instance_id AND e.app_id = ca.app_id)
    WHERE e.instance_id = $instance_id
        AND ca.category_id IN ($category_id1, $category_id2)
    GROUP BY ca.category_id, e.status;
```

When I do `EXPLAIN` on mysql I do get this result:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------+------------------+---------+----------------+--------+----------+-----------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys           | key              | key_len | ref            | rows   | filtered | Extra                             |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------+------------------+---------+----------------+--------+----------+-----------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e     | ref    | (will paste below)*     | PRIMARY          | 110     | const          | 4716   | 100      | Using temporary; Using filesort   |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ca    | ref    | PRIMARY                 | PRIMARY          | 146     | func           | 10     | 5        | Using where; Using index          |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------+------------------+---------+----------------+--------+----------+-----------------------------------+
```

**possible keys PASTED =** `PRIMARY,instance_id,app_end_index,instance_title_index,user_index,type_index`

**Data:**

App table contains 30M+ records.
App Category Apps contains 1M+ records.

**Usage:**

When query for multiple categories, like 50 in `IN ($category_id1, $category_id2)` I do get a query response in 2sec+

So my question would be is there a way to make this query more performant and perform in less than a sec when I query for multiple categories?
Also is there an index which should I be missing?

Comment: What is the definition of Key IDX_userid_score?

Comment: Sorry, I did misscopy from table example of `EXPLAIN`, actually it is `Primary` as well.

Answer (score 1):

These indexes *may* help:

```
ca:  INDEX(category_id, instance_id,  app_id)
e:  INDEX(instance_id,  status, app_id)
```

If the tables are huge, the use of UUIDs for indexes is problematic.

Comment: A SQL sandbox (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3c377d/1), it seems to work but some representative data may help to refine analysis